# Query by Pair groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the following table:

```
TABLE TEST

ID | NAME1 | NAME2
1  | 1     | 2
1  | 1     | 3
1  | 2     | 1
1  | 2     | 3
2  | 1     | 2
2  | 1     | 3
3  | 1     | 2
...
```

I want to query the IDs of the records by the list of pairs of `(NAME1, NAME2)` values.
It's kind of searching a parent record by children but the table is not defined in a hierarchical structure.

i.e. query by `[(1, 2), (1, 3)]` should produce the following result:

```
QUERY RESULT

ID | NAME1 | NAME2
2  | 1     | 2
2  | 1     | 3
```

So far what I've achieved is:

```
select *
from TEST as T
where exists (
    select *
    from (VALUES(1, 2), (1, 3)) as V(NAME1, NAME2)
    where T.NAME1 = V.NAME1 AND T.NAME2= V.NAME2
)
```

Which returns:

```
1  | 1     | 2
1  | 1     | 3
2  | 1     | 2
2  | 1     | 3
3  | 1     | 2
```

But what I need is an exact match per `ID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want the ids.  You can use aggregation:

```
with pairs as (
      select *
      from (values (1, 2), (1, 3)) v(name1, name2)
     )
select id
from test t left join
     pairs p
     on t.name1 = p.name1 and t.name2 = p.name2
group by id
having count(*) = count(p.name1) and
       count(*) = (select count(*) from pairs);
```

Comment: That's very neat. Thanks!